# SonarQube failing to analyze auto-generated target framework moniker files

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube 5.2 and MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner to analyze a solution containing a number of C# projects. When the runner encounters auto-generated files like...

```
bin\Release\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs
bin\Release\.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile7.AssemblyAttributes.cs
```

...it fails with the following error...

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The folder 'C:\Source\Project1\bin\Release\.NETFramework' does not exist for 'TheProject:TheBranch:TheProject:TheBranch:GUID' (base directory = C:\Source\Project1)
```

At the moment I'm working around the problem by deleting those files before invoking the runner with the 'end' verb, but would like to know if there is a better way or if this is a known bug.

Can anyone tell me if SonarQube should be able to handle these files, or if there is a configuration I should tweak to avoid the problem?

Comment: This isn't a known issue. The problem seems to be that the file name contains characters that the sonar-runner doesn't like; the code in in the generated can be analysed successfully if it's in a different file. Out of interest, what type of project template did you use to create the project, and have you tweaked any of the project properties to change where artefacts are built to? If I create a portable class library project, the files are generated to the %TEMP% directory, and they are automatically excluded from the analysis because they are not under the project directory.

Comment: @duncanpMS, you're absolutely right. As it turns out, the project had a custom 'targets' file being pulled in with an 'Import Project' directive in the csproj file. The custom target deliberately moved the output folder of the moniker files to the assembly output folder. I'm guessing the file name handling is still a SonarQube bug, but if you want to put your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a known issue - thanks for reporting it. I've created [SONARMSBRU-199](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-199) to track it.

Normally XXXAssemblyInfo.cs files are generated under the %TEMP% directory so they are automatically excluded from the analysis as they are not under the project folder. However, it's a valid file name so it should be possible to analyse it if it happens to be created under the project directory.